# Convergence of series $ \frac1{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ (a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ two real sequences. Further we know that $ b_n \to b$ and

$$ \lim_n\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-b_k) \to 0$$

Is it true, and if so, how could I prove?

$$ \lim_n\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \to b$$

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You do know the result of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_k^n b_k$? If not, that would be the place to start with. (As $n\rightarrow \infty$ of course).

Comment: Smells like [Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)...

Comment: @J.M. He's been dead for over a century now. Interesting that you can still smell him now, and from half a globe away too!

Comment: Cesàro is a variety of cheese, @AsafKaragila!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n b_k=b$.

Towards this end, let $\epsilon>0$.

Choose $M$ so that 
$|b_k-b|<\epsilon $ for all $k\ge  M$. Now write
$$
\tag{1}{1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\, b_k = {1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^M b_k+{1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=M+1}^n b_k.
$$

Now$$\tag{2}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^M b_k=0.$$ 
Also:
$$ (b-\epsilon){ n- M \over n}\le  {1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=M+1}^n b_k 
\le (b+\epsilon) {n- M  \over n}.$$ 
Taking limits as $n\rightarrow\infty$ of the above gives
$$\tag{3} 
(b-\epsilon) \le \liminf_n\, {1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=M+1}^n b_k 
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\limsup_n\, {1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=M+1}^n b_k 
\le (b+\epsilon) .$$

Since $\epsilon$ was an arbitrary positive number,  it follows from (1), (2), and (3) that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{1\over n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n b_k=b$.

Now write
$$\eqalign{
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {1\over n} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{1\over n} \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-b_k+b_k)\cr
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-b_k)
  + \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} {1\over n} \sum_{k=1}^n b_k \cr
&=0+b\cr
&=b.
}
$$

Comment: Slight mistake: in the inequality between (2) and (3), it should be n-M in the numerator, not n-(M+1).

Comment: @user18063 Yes, thank you.